# Roots of $f(x)=x^{p^2-p}+1$ over algebraically closed fields of positive characteristic.

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, roots

I don't know if this question is trivial or not, however I'm looking for the solution of the polynomial $f(x)=x^{p^2-p}+1$, as indicated above, over some algebraically closed field $\mathbb{F}$ of positive characteristic $p>0$. What can be said about it? How much the base field interferes to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your polynomial is $(x^{p-1}+1)^p$, hence there are $p-1$ distinct solutions, each with multiplicity $p$.

The solutions are precisely the square roots of elements in $\mathbb F_p$, which are not contained in $\mathbb F_p$.

I.e. if $a_1, \dotsc, a_{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ are the quadratic non-residues in $\mathbb F_p$, the roots of your poylnomial are given by $\pm \sqrt{a_i}$ with $1 \leq i \leq \frac{p-1}{2}$. Clearly they are all contained in $\mathbb F_{p^2}$.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it's very enlightening! so if I understand correctly we know beforehand that the number roots is $p-1$ always?

Comment: If my answer would have been enlightening to you, you might have figured out that there are $p-1$ roots. I made this explicit twice.

Comment: Interesting....